# Windows 10 Computer Wakes During Night

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, powercfg

Since I've updated my computer to win 10, it's been waking up in the middle of the night (it's important to note that this DID NOT happen before I updated, in windows 7). I'm not sure at what time it wakes up (as far as I can tell, it varies), but consistently, whenever I get out of bed, it's awake. I've actually researched this pretty extensively, and I've done everything that I know of to try and get it to stop. I disabled waking the computer for all WMC tasks (and looked through the rest of the tasks to see if the culprit was there, which it wasn't), I set the "automatic maintenance" time to noon, and in the device manager, I prevented all of my hardware devices from waking it. At first, the `powercfg -lastwake` command yielded that my networking adapter had woken the computer, but I disabled that. Now, the computer wakes, and, according to windows, nothing woke it. The command `powercfg -waketimers` also yields that there are no active wake timers. Below, I'll put the output of various `powercfg` commands, in the hope that someone will be able to use them.

```
λ powercfg -waketimers
There are no active wake timers in the system.


λ powercfg -requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
[DRIVER] Realtek High Definition Audio (HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0900&SUBSYS_1462D916&REV_1000\4&2340e212&0&0001)
An audio stream is currently in use.
[DRIVER] \FileSystem\srvnet
An active remote client has recently sent requests to this machine.

AWAYMODE:
None.

EXECUTION:
None.

PERFBOOST:
None.

λ powercfg -lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 0
```

Comment: Do you have a cat?

Comment: @goblinbox nope

Comment: did you check what time it's set to check for updates? - it usually defaults to something like 3am

Comment: @Tetsujin I went through all of the Task Scheduler items (and I mean _all_), and rescheduled or disabled waking on all of the ones that occur before 10 AM. In addition to that, I rescheduled the "automatic maintenence" to occur at noon.

Answer (score 0):

May be due to the Ethernet card...

1. Right click on **Start**
2. **Device Manager**
3. **Network Adapters**
4. Right click on *your card*
5. **Power Management**
6. Either disable '**Allow this device to wake up the computer**' or check '**Only allow magic packet to wake the computer**' if you need to Wake Over Lan...

Comment: I actually put in the OP that, for a while, that may have been what was waking it, but I disabled it about a week and a half ago.

Comment: Have you tried to disable other peripherals such as mouse and keyboard? Just ruling out a few things...

Comment: Yup. I looked through all of my hardware devices an disabled anything with the option.

Comment: Have you installed anything since you updated to Win10? (you can always try and use the force if everything else fails...)

Comment: Only noticeable things other than a few steam games are ccleaner, fraps, and f.lux (and, unfortunately, I destroyed the Jedi Academy just short of when I was scheduled for the IT part of my force training).

Comment: f.lux is a nifty program... I will try it... anyways you might want to uninstall it and see if that's the culprit as it probably runs in the background as far as I can tell and it obviously keeps track of the time of the day... I don't know how it works in the specific but it might be what wakes you pc up... try for a couple night without it and see...