# How can I stop, once and for all, Windows 10 from waking up on its own?

Tags: windows-10

Duplicate: [Conclusively stop wake timers from waking Windows 10 desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/973009/conclusively-stop-wake-timers-from-waking-windows-10-desktop/973029#973029) -- there are conclusive answers there. I searched before asking this, didn't find that question.

I've gone through about 5 posts about this issue. I'll go and fix it and then about a week later it starts up again. I'm sitting 10 feet away from the computer and it just started up again.

It's getting old. I need a list of things to check -- things that might be causing this behavior and how to stop them. I suspect that it is Windows Update helpfully resetting it's ability to wake up and check for updates.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> powercfg -waketimers
Timer set by [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SystemEventsBroker) expires at 6:46:52 PM o
n 1/10/2016.
  Reason: Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\Media Center\mcupdate_scheduled' scheduled task that requested
 waking the computer.
```

Comment: Open up an admin command prompt and type in `powercfg -lastwake`. What does the cause appear to be?

Comment: [Similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/963888/windows-10-computer-wakes-during-night?rq=1)

Comment: `powercfg -lastwake` doesn't help me if I've put the PC to sleep since it happened

Comment: Please observe my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/973009/conclusively-stop-wake-timers-from-waking-windows-10-desktop/973029#973029).

Comment: @jcollum no worries, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there is a task on the PC that is telling it to wake up once a week to do what it has to do. Check the Task Scheduler on the PC for any tasks that tell it to wake up.

There is also the good possibility that it is Windows Update waking your PC up. Although it is not recommended, you can set it to "Never check for updates" and do your own manual updates one a week or so.

Another possibility is a Wake-On-LAN event which is telling your PC to wake up, disable it in your BIOS if this is the case. While you are there, make sure there isn't a schedule in your BIOS which is telling your PC to wake up.

That is all I can think of that could cause it to wake up every week or so...

Comment: Looks like mcupdate_scheduled is the issue, see updated post

Comment: I've marked this question as a duplicate.